# Units in quotient rings

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, inverse

Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of a ring $R=\mathbb{K}[X_1, \dots, X_m]/K$, quotient of a polynomial ring over a field $\mathbb{K}$.

Consider the map
$$\begin{aligned}
    (R/I)^*\oplus (R/J)^*&\longrightarrow (R/(I+J))^*\\
    (r, s)&\longmapsto (r\cdot s^{-1})
\end{aligned}
$$
where $(R/I)^*$ are the units of the quotient ring.

Is this map surjective, in this generality?
If so, can you point out a reference, or say to me why this should be trivial?
If not, can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: Clearly $(R/I)^*\longrightarrow (R/(I+J))^*$ is not surjective, but I cannot find a counterexample or a reason for which the above should not be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had asked the question over any field and not specifically $\mathbb{K}$ (which I read as $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) I would have the following answer:

Take $R= \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$, $I=(X^2-2)$, $J=(Y^2-3)$.
Then in $R/(I+J)=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3]$ we have $(Y-X)(Y+X)=Y^2-X^2=1$.
It's impossible (in $R/(I+J)$) to write $Y-X$ as the product of two polynomials of which one is only in $X$ and the other only in $Y$, so it's not in the image.

For the case you posted I have the following similar idea:

Consider $R=\mathbb{C}[X,Y,Z,W]$, $I=(XY-1)$, $J=(ZW-1,XW+YZ)$.

Then in $R/(I+J)$ we have $(X+Z)\frac{Y+W}{2} = \frac{XY+XW+YZ+ZW}{2}=1$ but in neither $R/I$ nor $R/J$ the element $X+Z$ can be a unit.

Until someone can make it clear why $X+Z$ can't factor into elements which are units in the respective rings this answer is, however, only partial.

Comment: No, it's not partial. $\mathbb{K}$ for me is any field and your answer answers greatly my request of a counterexample. Thank you! :)